# Watson Speech to Text - Add Custom Audio Resources in ZIP or tar.gz keeps failing

Tags: curl, speech-to-text, watson, transcription

1. I'm trying to add 17 MP3 files as audio resources in Speech To Text to build a custom acoustic model.
2. When I upload files individually they work fine.
3. When adding as a ZIP or tar.gz file, the system declares them invalid.
4. The ZIP and tarball were created on my Mac using the system tool for ZIP and Archive Utility for the tarball.

Here is the cURL command I'm passing to upload bulk files:

```
curl -X POST -u "username:password" \
 --header "Contained-Content-Type: audio/mp3" \
 --header "Content-Type: application/zip" \
 --data-binary @audio.zip \
 "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/acoustic_customizations/{customization ID removed}/audio/audio1
```

I'm using the same command to upload single files and it works fine, so something is strange with the add archive. I'm preparing to add almost 20 hours of audio after I get this working.

Comment: Usually the issue with ZIP files from Macs is that they add a hidden subfolder at the root. The service doesn't like this, you need a ZIP file with flat list of audio files. Can you check if that hidden sub-folder is there and remove it?

Comment: Thanks-- I'll give that a try.